# What does a red triangle mean in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl information and get my JSON file.
What does a red rectangle and red background mean?

1. [image]
2. [image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The red triangle is called a "Gutter Indicator".

It means a line has been deleted from the previous version of the file (based on Git).

Comment: You're right. And you can disable it by searching `diffDecorations` in settings and set it `none`

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio Code has an excellent integrated Git support for the most common commands. This makes it an excellent choice to manage your code commits while you develop.

For folders which are Git repositories, VS Code adds useful annotations to the gutter and to the overview ruler.

- A red triangle indicates where lines have been deleted
- A green bar indicates new added lines
- A blue bar indicates modified lines

Answer (score 1):

It was showing Git/VCS changes in Visual Studio Code.
For example:
 Blue color horizontal line - Edited , 
 Green color horizontal line - New

In your case it was: 
 Red color triangle - Deleted